# React-Native error when running with react-native run-android

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, build.gradle, version

I have some problems with React-Native. I tried to change react-native version or edit build.gradle moving google() or jcenter(), but the error still persist.

Can someone help me?
I think it's a problem of build.gradle, but I'm not sure.

**Environment:**

*React-Native*: "^0.59.10"

*NodeJS*: "v10.16.3"

*project/android/build.gradle*:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

        maven {
           url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // Check for v3.1.2 or higher
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'  // Google Services plugin

        // Add dependency
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'  // Crashlytics plugin

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter{
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }

        //google()
    }
}


wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

*project/android/app/src/build.gradle*:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'EvilIcons.ttf' ] // Name of the font files you want to copy
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0.4"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a":3, "x86_64":4 ]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

configurations.all { resolutionStrategy { force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0' } }
dependencies {
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-sensitive-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-iap')
    implementation project(':react-native-exit-app')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_netinfo')
    implementation project(':react-native-android-location-enabler')
    implementation project(':lottie-react-native')
    implementation project(':react-native-restart')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box')
    implementation project(':react-native-geocoder')
    implementation project(':react-native-navigation')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'

    // (Recommended) Add Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.1'

    // Add dependency
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'


    //FOR GIF
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.1.0'

    // For animated GIF support
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.+'

    // For WebP support, including animated WebP
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.+'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.+' 



}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5"
      }
    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here's the output of the error:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preReleaseBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/2.1.0/fresco-2.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/2.1.0/fresco-2.1.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/animated-gif/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/animated-gif/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/animated-gif/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/animated-webp/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/animated-webp/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/animated-webp/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/webpsupport/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/webpsupport/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/webpsupport/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from 
server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-iap
      > Could not resolve com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/billingclient/billing/1.1/billing-1.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/billingclient/billing/1.1/billing-1.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from 
server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :lottie-react-native
      > Could not resolve com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5.
         > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/airbnb/android/lottie/2.5.5/lottie-2.5.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/airbnb/android/lottie/2.5.5/lottie-2.5.5.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.0.6.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-navigation
      > Could not resolve com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.0.6.
         > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/2.0.6/ahbottomnavigation-2.0.6.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/2.0.6/ahbottomnavigation-2.0.6.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu-toolbar:1.5.4.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-navigation
      > Could not resolve com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu-toolbar:1.5.4.
         > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/balysv/materialmenu/material-menu-toolbar/1.5.4/material-menu-toolbar-1.5.4.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/balysv/materialmenu/material-menu-toolbar/1.5.4/material-menu-toolbar-1.5.4.pom'. 
Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.infer.annotation:infer-annotation:0.11.2.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.10
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.infer.annotation:infer-annotation:0.11.2.
         > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/infer/annotation/infer-annotation/0.11.2/infer-annotation-0.11.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/infer/annotation/infer-annotation/0.11.2/infer-annotation-0.11.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.10
      > Could not resolve javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.10
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/2.1.0/fresco-2.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/2.1.0/fresco-2.1.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.10.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.10
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.10.0.
         > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/imagepipeline-okhttp3/1.10.0/imagepipeline-okhttp3-1.10.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/fresco/imagepipeline-okhttp3/1.10.0/imagepipeline-okhttp3-1.10.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.6.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.10
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.6.0.
         > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/soloader/soloader/0.6.0/soloader-0.6.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/soloader/soloader/0.6.0/soloader-0.6.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.10
      > Could not resolve com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2.
         > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.10
      > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.12.1/okhttp-3.12.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.12.1/okhttp-3.12.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.12.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.10
      > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.12.1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp-urlconnection/3.12.1/okhttp-urlconnection-3.12.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp-urlconnection/3.12.1/okhttp-urlconnection-3.12.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.10
      > Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0.
         > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.15.0/okio-1.15.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.15.0/okio-1.15.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: 
Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.3.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0 > com.google.firebase:firebase-common:18.0.0
      > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.3.
         > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-annotations/1.6.3/auto-value-annotations-1.6.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value-annotations/1.6.3/auto-value-annotations-1.6.3.pom'. 
Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error clearly states that fresco library is missing in android, please add those in your gradle file manually https://github.com/facebook/fresco
 and your issue will be fixed, if you're adding any library do not forget to link it. And one advice move to latest version of react-native.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I added "implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.1.0'", but the error doesn't go away. I have update my question, posting my build.gradle file inside android/app/ folder and the new console output.

Comment: Then I update to react-native 0.62.2. 
Nothing has changed.

Comment: @DanieleMenchetti try to debug, the url is throwing 403, try to replace jcenter(), with maven { url 
 "https://jcenter.bintray.com" } this is https not http, as jcenter doesn't allow http request anymore

Comment: Yes, yesterday I saw this problem. Thank you so much for your help! :)